# SELECT, FROM, INNER JOIN, WHERE function

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have two tables "users" and "emp_details". "users" are Branch mangers who have login id for monitoring their own branch's employees. "emp_details" includes employees working for different branches which include branch managers aslo.

when Branch manager ("users") log in it should fetch details from "emp_details" only if this particular "users" branch (code: location) match.

```
SELECT emp_details.emp_no, emp_name, designation, emp_details.location
 FROM emp_details
 INNER JOIN users
 WHERE users.location = emp_details.location
```

used above code but showing data for all users created not as per the login-ed users location. Please help

Comment: There is nothing in your query about a specific `user`. How could it guess what records to filter?

Comment: user log-in with "username"  this is  emp_no in the table emp_details

Comment: Syntax error. Missing ON clause.

Comment: Username T120025      Branch  Al Qusais
Username        T100019      Branch  Sharjah                                                                            (if user   'T120025' loged-In,  it should filter employees who have branch/location same as T120025) that means list out those who work under Al Qusais Branch

Comment: Sample data and desired results in the question would really help.

Comment: Please look in to my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query it will give the output of all the data which have matching locations. 
If you want to get the data which belong to the location of the specific user, you have to filter that user from the query. Otherwise query will output all the matching data.

```
    DECLARE @UserName AS Varchar(50)

    SELECT ed.emp_no, ed.emp_name, ed.designation,ed.location
    FROM emp_details ed
    INNER JOIN users u ON u= ed.location
    WHERE u.User_Name = @UserName
```

Please note that above parameter can be user name or user ID or any relevant thing, but you have to pass that to the sql query.

Comment: [This is the "users" Table ][1]


[this is "emp_details" table][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY5Xy.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGspN.png

i want to get the data which belong to the location of the specific user who logged-in

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a `WHERE` clause -- after fixing your `WHERE` clause to be an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT ed.emp_no, ed.emp_name, ed.designation, ed.location
FROM emp_details ed JOIn
     users u
     ON u.location = ed.location
WHERE u.login_id = ?;
```

`?` is a parameter placeholder for the manager's login id.  That seems to be how you are identifying the users.

Comment: Please look in to my query